# angular 6 APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular

I have successfully implemented an angular 6 APP_INITIALIZER inside the AppModule.
The basic idea is, I need to load some user authorization information along with some other details before I run the application. All works well.

However, now I need to add a user-registraion section that requires no information from the backend server (and these calls will fail).

I tried to move all the code for APP_INITIALIZER into a submodule bascially figuring that I only need the piece to run once that module is loaded. however that code never executes.

Perhaps I am using  APP_INITIALIZER wrong?

Comment: [Edit] the question and show your [mcve] or we are all guessing.

Comment: why did you place user authentication logic under APP_INITIALIZER's factory. I can't think of a scenario it fits there.

Comment: APP_INITIALIZER seemed like ti solved the issue at the time. The application is a C# Aspnet core app. It uses Azure AD to authenticate. Basically when a user comes in, they are re-directed to MS Login page, then back to the app. Open to sugestions

Comment: Have you tried using `resolve` on the route into your module and load data you need over there?